# Saving .xlsx file as a .prn in Python

Tags: python, excel

I've written a script that has Python save the data in Pandas dataframe to an .xlsx file (the data is contained in a single sheet within the workbook called `sheet1`). I now need to have this data save in a .prn format, but I'm not having any luck. I tried using the `openpyxl` library as per below to accomplish this but the file that's export has these strange characters that looks nothing like the original data.

```
wb = load_workbook('Z:/...' + file_name)

new_file_name = 'Positive Pay ' + datetime.today().strftime("%Y-%m-%d") + '.prn'
wb.save('Z:/Positive Pay/' + new_file_name)
```

This saves the file in the .prn, but opening it with Notepad++ shows strange characters.

Comment: ...what do you mean by "strange characters"?

Comment: The text looks like its in the Wingdings font

Comment: quick test, just load the workbook and save back again. Same issue?